# How do I stretch out this table to fill the page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using React to render this page. I've copied the exact source code from a template and transferred it over into React but the page is only rendering at about half the size. I've played around with the div's and styling but still unable to get it to resize. Without using inline CSS, how can I stretch the table out to fill up the page and which div's and classes are causing it?

Thank you!

my code:

Comment: Do you have a demo that we can inspect? Maybe to copy HTML and CSS to something like https://jsfiddle.net/. If you inspect the code via chrome inspector, which is the first div that is not stretching fully? layout-content or the one below?

Comment: you can use flexbox css to stretch the table